# How to customize Room Database Query results that we can achieve in normal SQLite Open helper class

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, sqliteopenhelper

In `Room` database we write queries as `DAO` to get results from database. In normal SQLite OpenHelper class we can customize the query results as per our need.

```
public ArrayList<MyData> getMyData(String id) {
        ArrayList<MyData> entries=new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + MYDATA + " WHERE " + ID + " = ?";
        Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{id});
        List<String> business=new ArrayList<>();
        if(c2.moveToFirst()){
                MyData entry=new MyData();
                entry.setId(c2.getString(0));
                String dataValue=c2.getString(1);
                String val="";
                if(dataValue.contains("__")){
                    String[] valueSplit =dataValue.split("__");
                    if(valueSplit[0]!=null){
                        val=address[0];
                    }
                }else{
                    val="";
                }
                entries.add(entry);
            }
        return entries;
    }
```

In this query, results obtained from Database is customized based on some condition, added in ArrayList MyData object and then final result is returned. How it can be done in Room Database

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly you can use `@query` in your DAO like this

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM MYDATA WHERE id = :id")
public ArrayList<MyData> getMyData(String id);
```

Then in your database view model expose `getMyData(String id)` and process your data

Comment: Yes. That might be one of the the way. Thanks